# squid reverse proxy with multiple ports

Tags: reverse-proxy, squid

I have a reverse proxy in front of my virtual machines. All DNS records point to the public IP where squid3 lives and squid redirects the traffic on the port 80.

Now, I would like to enable other ports for HTTP, like 8080. I have this in my squid.conf:

```
http_port 80
http_port 8080
http_access allow all
cache_peer 192.168.0.50 parent 80 0 no-query originserver name=server_1
cache_peer_domain server_1 subdomain1.domain.tld
cache_peer 192.168.0.56 parent 80 0 no-query originserver name=server_2
cache_peer_domain server_2  subdomain2.domain.tld  domain2.tld
cache deny all
acl all src all
```

But squid does not really redirect to port 8080 on the server_1. Is it possible something like

```
cache_peer 192.168.0.50 parent * 0 no-query originserver name=server_1
```

Obviously the asterisk is not a valid port number and squid complains.

Thanks for any suggestions!